# Sanitize TextFormField value before validation in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use do some sanitization like trimming a string before the validator function is called. I don't want to do it in the `onChange` method but wait until the user finsehes his input.

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'Email*', hintText: "john.doe@gmail.com"),
  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
  validator: emailValidator,
  onChanged: (String str) {
  }
),
```

Comment: You are receiving a value inside the function of the validator why not doing it there before the actual validation ?

Comment: Thx. I tried which leads me to another problem described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58433116/building-a-wrapper-widget-for-a-formfield-and-controller-in-flutter