# building a wrapper widget for a formfield and controller in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I like to create a wrapper widget for a TextFormField which includes the controller because I have to access the value of the TextFormField inside the validation function. With the code pasted below, every time the MyTextField gets the focus the `contructor` and the `build` method were called again. This causes a recreationg of `myInputController` which causes that the textfield is empty every time I click on it.

```
class MyTextField extends StatelessWidget {

  TextEditingController myInputController;

  MyTextField() {
       myInputController = TextEditingController();
  } 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("build called");
    return TextFormField(
      controller: myInputController,
    );
  }
}
```

Inside the app I inserted the widget like this:

```
 ...
 child: SingleChildScrollView(
   child: Form(
     key: _formKey,
     child: Column(
       children: <Widget>[
       MyTextField(),
       TextFormField(
              ),
       ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use `Form()`widget then you should use `StatefulWidget` instead of `StatelessWidget`

So, you just want to use `StatefulWidget` in you code

Answer (score 0):

From the build method, return null.

And put this,

```
TextEditingController myInputController = new TextEditingController();
```

Instead of this,

```
TextEditingController myInputController;

MyTextField(){
    myInputController = TextEditingController();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried but unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem: Returning null from the build function throws this exception:  "A build function returned null.". I also changed the initialization of `myInputController` but I don't think it makes a difference.

Comment: @MarcS82 Hey, no need to create a stateless widget for the controller. Put it on the class that contains the textFormField